# How do you hook NewRelic monitoring into ExpressionEngine

Tags: performance, newrelic

I use NewRelic to monitor site performance, but since everything runs through index.php, the amount of data I get back regarding controller performance is limited and clumped together. How can I get more granular performance data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help ?

**Instrumenting ExpressionEngine with New Relic ( and Tracelytics )**
http://learningsomethingnewwith.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/instrumenting-expressionengine-with-tracelytics-and-new-relic/

Comment: I was just looking at that. It looks a little hacky (is that a word?) I wonder if a proper add-on could be built and if that article is a head start in right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented and it works well. It would be cool to do something cleaner with an extension of sorts..

Comment: I wrote that blog post. At the time the hooks system was at least one right way to implement it. Now that EE has native New Relic support, you'd probably definitely want to go with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI: EllisLab released New Relic monitoring in ExpressionEngine 2.7

http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.7.0-released (2nd sub head down)